# MFC ListBox Control: How CCheckListBox notifies "checkbox status changed"?

Tags: mfc

How `CCheckListBox` notifies "checkbox status changed"?

Thanks.....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the user changes a checkbox status in a `CCheckListBox`, an undocumented MFC-specific message is sent to parent window: `CLBN_CHKCHANGE`.
We can handle this message like in the following example:

```
 // MyDialog.h
 class CMyDialog : public CDialog
 {
   // ...
   afx_msg void OnCheckChangeMyList();
 };
  
  // MyDialog.cpp
  // ...
   ON_CONTROL(CLBN_CHKCHANGE, IDC_MY_LIST, OnCheckChangeMyList)
  END_MESSAGE_MAP()

   void CMyDialog::OnCheckChangeMyList()
  {
     // got it!
  }
```

Note: instead of `ON_CONTROL`, we can directly use `ON_CLBN_CHKCHANGE` macro.

```
   // ...
     ON_CLBN_CHKCHANGE(IDC_MY_LIST, OnCheckChangeMyList)
   // ...
```

---

### Update

It would seem that the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cchecklistbox-class?view=msvc-170) has now been updated to at least mention its existence. Even so, the **Add Handler** GUI still does not list this event handler.

To quote:

> There's only one message-map entry that pertains specifically to
> `CCheckListBox` (but see also the message-map entries for `CListBox`):
>
> `ON_CLBN_CHKCHANGE` The user has changed the state of an item's
> checkbox.